# Search function wrong number of argument (2 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, argument-passing

I am trying to implement a simple search function which triggers a number of argument error. Here 
My views

```
<%= form_tag(clients_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Clients" %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

The method in my controller

```
def index
if current_user.admin?
  if params[:search]
    @clients = Client.search(params[:search], load:true).result
  else
    @clients = Client.all.paginate(:per_page => 3, :page => params[:page])
  end
else
    @clients = current_user.clients
end
end
```

My model

```
def self.search(query)
  where("name like ?","%#{query}%") 
end
```

I get the error message "wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)". I don't see what is the other argument passed to the model. A fresh pair of eyes will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `search` method allow only one argument:

```
def self.search(query)
  where("name like ?","%#{query}%") 
end
```

But you trying to use it with 2:

```
@clients = Client.search(params[:search], load:true).result
                                        # ^^^^^^^^^^^ second argument
```

Comment: Thanks but now it triggers another issue (undefined method `result' for #<Client::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007ffa9abae388>).

Comment: so, remove `.result` from `Client.search(params[:search], load:true).result` what it should be do?

Comment: I used it initially to correct a bug with will_paginate that was triggering a undefined method total_pages. I have removed it and removed my pagination with will_paginate and try to find another way to paginate my application. Thanks.

Comment: Do you use a gem for pagination? Which one?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are passing two parameters.

```
@clients = Client.search(params[:search], load:true).result
```

But in Model you just take single parameter.

```
def self.search(query)
  where("name like ?","%#{query}%") 
end
```

You have to access  load:true in model method.

```
def self.search(query, load)
  where("name like ?","%#{query}%") 
end
```

or on the base of your requirements.